# Why won't the number repeat on this assignment? Java code input

Tags: java

In the following piece of code:

```
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in); 
    int num = 1;
    num = stdin.nextInt();
    do
    {
        if (num % 2 == 0)
         {
            System.out.print(num + " ");
        }

    }while(num > 0);
```

If a user enters an even number that is greater than 0 on this program, it is supposed to print the number again after a space, but it won't.  I looked up a YouTube video explaining this code, and they are doing the same code I am, but for some reason it won't work for me.

Here is the task:

Write a loop that reads positive integers  from standard input, printing out those values  that are even, each followed by a space, and that terminates when it reads an integer  that is not positive. Declare  any variables  that are needed.

ASSUME  the availability of a variable , stdin, that references  a Scanner object  associated with standard input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do it like this.

```
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in); 
int num = 1;
// uncomment if u not want to use default value
// num = stdin.nextInt();
do
{
    if (num % 2 == 0)
     {
        System.out.print(num + " ");
     }
    num = stdin.nextInt();
}
while(num > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the `nextInt` call inside the loop. Not only read it once.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the input once. Try doing :

```
int num;
do
{
    num = stdin.nextInt();
    if (num % 2 == 0)
    {
        System.out.print(num + " ");
    }
}while(num>0);
```

This way, you take input Each time the user enters a positive Number

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to read the value in your loop, you could move the read into the loop body; but you also need to test that the value isn't negative (I assume). Like,

```
int num;
do {
    num = stdin.nextInt();
    if (num > 0 && num % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.print(num + " ");
    }
} while (num > 0);
```

However, you could write it in a more *idiomatic* way (albeit less obviously); like

```
int num;
while ((num = stdin.nextInt()) > 0) {
    if (num % 2 == 0) { // <-- stop condition is checked before here.
        System.out.print(num + " ");
    }
}
```